# How to terminate user's sessions in Oracle DB exactly 8 hours after user connected?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to terminate user sessions (and optionally also lock the user), exactly 8 hours after user established DB connection. I tried creating a profile, but it just doesn't terminate user's sessions after 8h.   I use Oracle Enterprise DB 12c.

```
CREATE PROFILE "PROFILE_8H_EXPIRY" LIMIT
  SESSIONS_PER_USER UNLIMITED
  CPU_PER_SESSION UNLIMITED
  CPU_PER_CALL UNLIMITED
  CONNECT_TIME 480 -- Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in minutes.
  IDLE_TIME UNLIMITED
  LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION UNLIMITED
  LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL UNLIMITED
  COMPOSITE_LIMIT UNLIMITED
  PRIVATE_SGA UNLIMITED
  FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS UNLIMITED
  INACTIVE_ACCOUNT_TIME UNLIMITED
  PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME 0.33 -- Specify the number of days the same password can be used for authentication
  PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME UNLIMITED
  PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX UNLIMITED
  PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME UNLIMITED -- Specify the number of days an account will be locked after too many failed login attemps.
  PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME 0.33 --  If the password is not changed during the grace period marked in days, the password expires.
  PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION FUNCTION_8H_EXPIRY;

ALTER USER JOHN PROFILE PROFILE_8H_EXPIRY;
```

Comment: Was the profile assigned before or after the user logged in? Were there multiple sessions? Were they all established at the same time? Each session will have its own, separate 8 hour clock; they won't all terminate at once unless they were all established at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CREATE PROFILE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-PROFILE.html#GUID-ABC7AE4D-64A8-4EA9-857D-BEF7300B64C3)

> To specify resource limits for a user, you must:
>
> - Enable resource limits dynamically with the ALTER SYSTEM statement or with the initialization parameter RESOURCE_LIMIT. This parameter
>   does not apply to password resources. Password resources are always
>   enabled.

Check the `resource_limit` parameter.

Comment: I have altered system and enabled resource_limit and it now works. CONNECT_TIME value is the one that terminates user's sessions.  Additional question : is there any way once session is terminated, that user gets Locked at the same time?

Comment: @korodani That will not happen. Users can be locked manually or automatically by password rules (failed login attemptso, expiry).